# Mercurial Workflow: Need to track file in my local working copy, but not push to "trunk"

Tags: mercurial

This is my setup:

I have a main Mercurial repository (call it trunk). When I want to work on a feature, I do a clone and start working on it (usually add a bookmark as well).

I use various tools to do my work, which tend to generate convenient text files in the directory. It would be very helpful for me to track those files as well. However, I need to ensure those files do *not* get pushed to trunk.

In a sense, I'd like a "parallel" Mercurial repository in that directory where I can track these files.

How do people manage this? I'm open to using (stable) Mercurial extensions. Ideally, I do not want to "remember" to remove stuff before pushing to trunk.

Comment: Hello, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: patch queues and phases. Probably for what you want to do, phases are the less-friction approach. But there is no really "parallel" solution to my knowledge.

Have a look at `hg help phases` for an overview and `hg phase` for the command to manipulate the phase of a changeset.

To be sure you never push to trunk inadvertently, you have to make your commits "secret" by default (in your HOME/.hgrc):

```
  [phases]
  new-commit = secret
```

Then `hg push` will never allow to push anything by default, you would have to selectively change the phase of the changesets you want to push.

You could also not use the above configuration and use the `--secret` option of `hg commit` when committing something you want to keep for you, but it is too risky to forget.

Note that, both with patch queues and phases, you have to be proficient with history rewriting with `hg histedit`, to reshuffle around the commits.